# how to install pyevolve with python 2.7.5?

Tags: python, python-2.7, genetic-algorithm, genetic-programming, pyevolve

I have used [this](http://pyevolve.sourceforge.net/intro.html#downloads) tutorial and others. I have already tried dozens of times and have spent almost a complete day but I could not succeed.

No matter what, I could not go beyond this:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.5 (default, May 13 2016, 16:30:46) 
[GCC 4.9.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pyevolve
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pyevolve
>>>
```

P.S. *I don't know python.* I just have installed python using instructions available online and have run the tests to make sure its installed.

*I don't know much about pyevolve either.* I just have to install it to make my experiment run. The tool in my experiment has python scripts which   require pyevolve.

**EDIT:**

When I do: `easy_install pyevolve`

I get:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py:2512:  PEP440Warning: 'python-apt (0.9.3.11build1)' is being parsed as a legacy,  non PEP 440, version. You may find odd behavior and sort order. In  particular it will be sorted as less than 0.0. It is recommend to migrate    to PEP 440 compatible versions.
  PEP440Warning,
Searching for pyevolve
Best match: Pyevolve 0.6
Removing Pyevolve 0.6rc1 from easy-install.pth file
Adding Pyevolve 0.6 to easy-install.pth file

Using /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Processing dependencies for pyevolve
Finished processing dependencies for pyevolve
```

for `easy_install --upgrade pyevolve`

I get:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py:2512:  PEP440Warning: 'python-apt (0.9.3.11build1)' is being parsed as a legacy,  non PEP 440, version. You may find odd behavior and sort order. In  particular it will be sorted as less than 0.0. It is recommend to migrate  to PEP 440 compatible versions.
   PEP440Warning,
Searching for pyevolve
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/pyevolve/
Best match: Pyevolve 0.6rc1
Processing Pyevolve-0.6rc1-py2.7.egg
Removing Pyevolve 0.6 from easy-install.pth file 
Adding Pyevolve 0.6rc1 to easy-install.pth file
Installing pyevolve_graph.py script to /usr/local/bin

Using /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Pyevolve-0.6rc1-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for pyevolve
Finished processing dependencies for pyevolve
```

Comment: What exactly have you tried? Just easy_install?

Comment: `easy_install pyevolve`, `easy_install --upgrade pyevolve` and `easy_install /downloads/downloaded_package.egg`

Comment: What are the result? A error?

Comment: @malbarbo updated the question

Comment: It's a little interesting that you felt the need to install Python yourself. Linux generally comes with Python preinstalled. And if you installed it yourself, it's a little odd that you didn't install the latest Python 2.7.x (which is currently 2.7.11). Though I'm not a Linux user myself, so I can't really say; maybe 2.7.5 is normal for your Linux distribution.

Comment: @JohnY I am sorry. I could not understand what point are you trying to make?

Comment: No particular point, really. Just expressing my surprise. I would have thought your Linux already had Python, so you shouldn't have to install it yourself.

Comment: @JohnY I was not sure about it, but yes you are right. However, my need is a different version than the one already exists. A wild guess of mine could also be that this is due to these multiple python installations -- though no idea how to fix. Nonetheless, I don't have any idea about python...